# CSVHelper, C#, List

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am trying to read multiple records types from a csv file where the first line have following records

id, 
name, 
Number of values

and the second line have

date, 
shift, 
values[0..n],
quality

With the help from original csvhelper [example](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-multiple-record-types/) i can read the original lines but i can not figure out how to pass BarMap the number of values that need to be aggregated

`fooRecords.Add(csv.GetRecord<Foo>());`
Foo.numValue <- Number of values

`barRecords.Add(csv.GetRecord<Bar>());`

```
public sealed class BarMap : ClassMap<Bar>
{
    public BarMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.date).Index(1);
        Map(m => m.shift).Index(2);
        //Aggregation of values 1 ..n goes here
        Map(m => m.quality).Index(n+1);

    }
}
```

I would appreciate if anyone can help me in this.

Comment: If there are not a fixed amount of values, e.g. always the same number of values per row, then I would imagine this helper will struggle as it is mapping fixed classes and doesn't look to handle arrays/lists.  I think you'll either need to ask the author directly or roll your own.

Comment: What i was thinking is that if i can pass on the numValues to Bar mapper class, i should be able to iterate on those values to get the aggregate. Does this seem like a possibility ?

Comment: That sounds feasible if there is always the same number of Values.  If there is a different number of values per row, it would be more difficult.

Comment: Can you give me an example for same number of values. I would then play around with that idea to see how i can make it work for dynamic values.

Comment: It is probably just easy not to use CSVHelper and parse the file just using streamreader.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially about writing titles. The current title is just a number of keywords, not an actual question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do aggregation, you can use `ConvertUsing`. https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/inline-type-conversion

The function passes in the `IReaderRow` and you need to return the value that gets set to the property. Since you have the row, you can pull anything you want from any field and create the value that gets set.

Example:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    s.AppendLine("Id,A,B");
    s.AppendLine("1,2,3");
    using (var reader = new StringReader(s.ToString()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
        csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList().Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Sum { get; set; }
}

public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.Sum).ConvertUsing(row => row.GetField<int>("A") + row.GetField<int>("B"));
    }
}
```

If you want all the rest of the fields put into a `List` or something like that, you can do this.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    s.AppendLine("Id,A,B");
    s.AppendLine("1,2,3");
    using (var reader = new StringReader(s.ToString()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
        csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList().Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<int> TheRest { get; set; }
}

public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.TheRest).Index(1);
    }
}
```

You can specify an ending index too.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Great pointer on ConvertUsing. I ended up doing

```
Map(m => m.date).Index(1);
Map(m => m.shift).Index(2);
Map(m => m.IntervalValue).ConvertUsing(row =>
        {
            double sumVal = 0;
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    sumVal += row.GetField<double>(i + 2);                    
                }
            };
                    
            return sumVal;
        });
Map(m => m.quality).Index(13);    //2 fields + 10 numbers
```

Comment: One more question here, i have hardcoded 10 and then 13 because of number of values.Can i pass it from Foo Class.It is only a number that tells me number of integers to expect in Bar class. There are other fields before and after these numbers

Comment: If it's not per row, you can add constructor parameters to `FooMap`. You then create the map using `new` and register the instance instead. `RegisterClassMap(fooMap)`

Comment: It is per row actually. Every other row tells me how many numbers to expect on next row. and the pattern continues.

Comment: I would suggest reading a single row at a time then. https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-by-hand

Comment: Thanks. Will try that